# NHibernate instantiate collections on save

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate to persist my entities in the database. MY entities have some relationships between them resulting into some mapped collections. I my case I use the Iesi.ISet interface to map these collections. I was wondering if it's possible for nhibernate to check if the properties containing those collections to be automatically set when I execute save if they are null.

This is how it should work. I have a property with a collection called "MyCollection" that is null before I save it to the database. I want NHibernate to set a collection to that property so that it's not null anymore on save. Is this possible?

Comment: Instantiate them yourself in entity constructors and never have them null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what your constructors are for.

If you very much want to hide such initialization behind NHibernate you might be able to inject the code for this using an NHibernate interceptor or event listener.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is the solution to what the poster want to accomplish.